# How to execute multiple update queries using jooq execute or batch execute without code generation?

Tags: java, oracle, sql-update, jooq, batch-updates

I am using JOOQ ( 3.10. 5 ) to update records in ORACLE table without jooq auto code generation in below ways

**Approach 1- Using DSL execute by using plain SQL String**

```
dslContext.execute("update author set first_name = 'updateTest-111111' where id = 1 ");
logger.info("1st update Done ");

dslContext.execute("update author set first_name = 'updateTest-2222222' where id = 2 ");
logger.info("2nd update Done ");
```

**Approach 2 - Using DSL batch by passing Query list**

```
List<Query> updateQueries = new ArrayList<>();

updateQueries.add(dslContext.parser().parseQuery("update author set first_name = 'updateTest-111' where id = 1 "));

updateQueries.add(dslContext.parser().parseQuery("update author set first_name = 'updateTest-222' where id = 2 "));

dslContext.batch(updateQueries).execute();
```

But in both cases, it is just updating 1st record and then stop execution , keeps on running.

**Below is the output for Approach -1**

```
2022-05-13 02:43:50.848  INFO 25524 --- [nio-9010-exec-1] org.jooq.Constants                       : 
                                      
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@  @  @  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  Thank you for using jOOQ 3.10.5
                                      
2022-05-13 02:43:50.922  WARN 25524 --- [nio-9010-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : minIdle is larger than maxActive, setting minIdle to: 5
2022-05-13 02:43:50.923  WARN 25524 --- [nio-9010-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 5
2022-05-13 02:43:52.670  INFO 25524 --- [nio-9010-exec-1] c.d.e.dao.ECRebootServiceDaoImpl         : 1st update Done
```

As you can see it stopped after 1st update Done.

How i should be executing multiple update queries using JOOQ ? or is there any better way to do this in JOOQ without code generation?

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem you encountered

The most likely reason for the problem you've encountered is that you have locked the row in another transaction (e.g. in a SQL editor?) and now your program is blocked right after printing the debug message, in the update.

#### Regarding your queries

With both of your approaches, you're not using bind variables, which will be a problem for Oracle's cursor cache, producing cursor cache contention. At the least, you should execute something like this:

```java
ctx.execute("update author set first_name = ? where id = ?", "updateTest-111111", 1);
ctx.execute("update author set first_name = ? where id = ?", "updateTest-2222222", 2);
```

In the batch case, you have used the jOOQ parser to get a `Query` representation of your string, but in your case, that seems to be overkill. You can wrap any [plain SQL string](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) in a `Query` using [`DSLContext.query(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#query(java.lang.String)).

In that case, again, it would be better to use bind variables, e.g. like this:

```java
ctx.batch(query("update author set first_name = ? where id = ?"))
   .bind("updateTest-111", 1)
   .bind("updateTest-222", 2)
   .execute();
```

Or even just:

```java
ctx.batch("update author set first_name = ? where id = ?")
   .bind("updateTest-111", 1)
   .bind("updateTest-222", 2)
   .execute();
```

#### Regarding code generation

[I suggest you reconsider using code generation](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/). While there isn't much benefit in your particular case (at least the parts you've shared in this question), it is very useful in general.

Comment: I tried  using code generation but got below issue , so believe it need enterprise license 

13:14:52.028 [main] INFO org.jooq.util.GenerationTool - Initialising properties  : C:\Users\TestUser\IdeaProjects\ccb-data-eucservice\library.xml
13:14:55.889 [main] WARN org.jooq.util.GenerationTool - Type not found           : Your configured database type was not found. This can have several reasons:
- You want to use a commercial jOOQ Edition, but you pulled the Open Source Edition from Maven Central.
- You have mis-typed your class name.

Comment: @codiacTushki: Yes, the jOOQ Open Source Edition doesn't support the Oracle dialect, only the commercial editions do.

Comment: I am using below dependency for codegen now 
 <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.5</version>
Is there any different dependency for enterprise one. I want to check on our local artifact if enterprise one is present or not

Comment: @codiacTushki: Does this help? https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-maven/

Comment: Thanks, it is having information which I was looking for